# Has anyone successfully used python's mapping on a function to calculate with buffers?

Tags: dictionary, dask, raster, numba

I'm currently working with raster data and there's one task I have to do which is counting the pixels in a buffer (a circle of a radius R drawn around a pixel). In my case specifically, I'm trying to count 7 different types of pixel values from 1 to 7. The function also uses a mask to determine which pixel is worth buffering or not. I've written my code to run in normal for loops, but as the radius R increase, the computing times gets longer and longer. Here is my code:

```
def getValueAroundPoint(img_data, geotransform, lat, lon, width, dtype, region_mask):
    result = np.array((), dtype = np.float32)
    if img_data is None:
        return None    

    offset_x = (lat - geotransform[3])/geotransform[5]
    offset_y = (lon - geotransform[0])/geotransform[1]

    if width == 2:
        return np.array([-9999], dtype = np.float32)

    evenWidth = ((width%2)==0)
    radius = (width-1)/2.0

    maxOffset = int(np.floor(radius))

    if evenWidth:
        maxOffset = maxOffset + 1
        center_offset_x = np.ceil(offset_x)
        center_offset_y = np.floor(offset_y)
    elif not evenWidth:
        center_offset_x = int(np.floor(offset_x) + 0.5)
        center_offset_y = int(np.floor(offset_y) + 0.5)

    minOffset = int(np.floor(radius) * -1)

    if region_mask is not None:
        if (region_mask[int(center_offset_x)][int(center_offset_y)]==0):
            for y in range(minOffset, maxOffset + 1):
                for x in range(minOffset, maxOffset + 1):
                    double_x = float(x)
                    double_y = float(y)

                    real_x = int(center_offset_x - double_x)
                    real_y = int(center_offset_y + double_y)

                    if evenWidth:
                
                        double_x = double_x - 0.5 
                        double_y = double_y - 0.5  

                        real_x = int(center_offset_x - (double_x + 0.5))
                        real_y = int(center_offset_y + (double_y + 0.5))

                    distance = np.sqrt((double_x * double_x) + (double_y * double_y))
                    if (0 < real_x < img_data.shape[0]) and (0 < real_y < img_data.shape[1]):
                        if (distance <= radius) and (img_data[real_x][real_y] != -9999) and (not np.isnan(img_data[real_x][real_y])):
                            result = np.append(result, img_data[real_x][real_y])

    else:
        for y in range(minOffset, maxOffset + 1):
            for x in range(minOffset, maxOffset + 1):
                double_x = float(x)
                double_y = float(y)

                real_x = int(center_offset_x - double_x)
                real_y = int(center_offset_y + double_y)

                if evenWidth:
            
                    double_x = double_x - 0.5 
                    double_y = double_y - 0.5  

                    real_x = int(center_offset_x - (double_x + 0.5))
                    real_y = int(center_offset_y + (double_y + 0.5))

                distance = np.sqrt((double_x * double_x) + (double_y * double_y))
                if (0 < real_x < img_data.shape[0]) and (0 < real_y < img_data.shape[1]):
                    if (distance <= radius) and (img_data[real_x][real_y] != -9999) and (not np.isnan(img_data[real_x][real_y])):
                        result = np.append(result, img_data[real_x][real_y])

    if (result.size > 0):
        count_1 = count(result, 1)
        count_2 = count(result, 2)
        count_3 = count(result, 3)
        count_4 = count(result, 4)
        count_5 = count(result, 5)
        count_6 = count(result, 6)
        count_7 = count(result, 7)
        return np.array([count_1, count_2, count_3, count_4, count_5, count_6, count_7], dtype=np.float32)
    else:
        return np.array([-9999, -9999, -9999, -9999, -9999, -9999, -9999], dtype=np.float32)
```

I'm trying to switch to mapping and eventually dask with numba to boost the performance of my code. But I'm still new to mapping on python and I can't find the material related to my problem on the internet. I'm stuck on how to transform some of the iterables to fit with the map() function because, for example: the lat and lon arguments will be calculated using the index of the for loops. Has everyone experienced this type of problem before and what are you solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

The function you posted is rather complex, there are a lot of nested loops and conditionals. While it is possible to achieve some parallelisation by wrapping your function with `delayed`, it will be much better to refactor the function, identifying chunks of code that could be extracted into their own functions (which can then be parallelised). The example below is just a rough sketch, I don't know what's happening in the function, but maybe it can serve as a starting point:

```py
# refactor the code that begins with the following two loops
#           for y in range(minOffset, maxOffset + 1):
#                for x in range(minOffset, maxOffset + 1):
def custom_func(x,y, img_data):
  double_x = float(x)
  double_y = float(y)

  real_x = int(center_offset_x - double_x)
  real_y = int(center_offset_y + double_y)

  if evenWidth:
                
    double_x = double_x - 0.5 
    double_y = double_y - 0.5  

    real_x = int(center_offset_x - (double_x + 0.5))
    real_y = int(center_offset_y + (double_y + 0.5))

    distance = np.sqrt((double_x * double_x) + (double_y * double_y))
    if (0 < real_x < img_data.shape[0]) and (0 < real_y < img_data.shape[1]):
        if (distance <= radius) and (img_data[real_x][real_y] != -9999) and (not np.isnan(img_data[real_x][real_y])):
             return img_data[real_x][real_y]
```

This way function `custom_func` can be computed in parallel for various `x` and `y` parameter values. For example, it can be wrapped with `delayed` to achieve better parallelisation:

```
import dask
@dask.delayed
def custom_func(x,y,img_data):
# the rest of the code

# later you can do
delayeds = [custom_func(x,y) for x in range(minOffset, maxOffset + 1) for y in range(minOffset, maxOffset + 1)]

# when you are ready to compute the values
results = dask.compute(delayeds)
```